# Does ndb.toplevel break transactions?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, asynchronous, transactions, app-engine-ndb

The following code works as expected and does not trigger the assertion:

```
@ndb.transactional
@ndb.tasklet
def Foo():
  assert ndb.in_transaction()
```

---

The following code breaks, triggering the assertion:

```
@ndb.transactional
@ndb.toplevel
def Foo():
  assert ndb.in_transaction()
```

I tried replacing the decorator with an ndb.transaction call or an ndb.transaction_async call, but neither worked.

Is there a bug with ndb.toplevel and transactions?

Comment: The only purpose of `ndb.toplevel` is to set a fresh default context. So I don't understand the use of `ndb.transactional(ndb.toplevel(Foo()))`. Why need you to create a transaction AND then delete it's context?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered that the problems is that both create new contexts.  transactional creates a context and ensures that all writes that happen inside of it are non-conflicting.  toplevel creates a context and ensures that all futures that are created inside of it are resolved.

As a result, toplevel is clobbering transaction's context.  The two just can't be combined in their current implementation.