# Normal async and Transaction async not working together

Tags: python, google-app-engine, asynchronous, google-cloud-datastore

I'm getting some weird results with my code. The first time I run the code, only the async functions from futures are saved to the datastore, **but none of the transactions were**. In the other hand, the trace shows me that the **transactions were committed**. When I run the same code where futures is empty, the transactions are stored in the datastore. What I'm doing wrong here?

pseudo-code

```
def check_users():
  def callback(user,account):
    return ndb.put_multi_async([user,account])
  transactions = []
  futures = []
  users = Users.query().fetch(100)
  for user in users:
    if user.active:
      account = Account.query(parent=user.key).order(-Account.date).get()
      account.active = True
      user.has_account = True
      transactions.append(ndb.transanction_async(lambda:callback(user,account),xg=true))
      continue
    user.count += 1
    futures.append(user.put_async())

  for transanction in transactions:
    futures = trasanction.get_result()
    for future in futures:
      future.check_result()

  for future in futures:
    future.check_result()
```

[image: trace list]

**UPDATED**
Second [Does ndb.toplevel break transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506231/does-ndb-toplevel-break-transactions), a transaction creates a new context that is conflicting with the other async method. I'm wondering if the same issue is happening with my code.Here is the answer for the question:

> I discovered that the problems is that both create new contexts. transactional creates a context and ensures that all writes that happen inside of it are non-conflicting. toplevel creates a context and ensures that all futures that are created inside of it are resolved.

Comment: How are you checking that the data was or wasn't written. If you are checking with a query then you may well just be experiencing an artifact of eventual consistency.  You should check the outcome by getting the object by the key.

Comment: Also, you're using ndb, which hits memcache BEFORE hitting the database. Maybe that's part of the issue as well?

Comment: @TimHoffman I'm getting all the entities modified using the Google Developer Console and only the ones that should be included in the transaction aren`t changed. Consequently, I used a get by id and the result repeats. To prove that I'm right, I just repeat all the process and the values ,which are part of the transactions, changed as soon as I run the function again. I just flushed the cache before another test and the results are consistent, as you said, ndb does hit before the database, but it will not affect anything here  @Patrice .

Comment: it maybe the writes overwriting each other. You're not using transaction properly. To use appengine transaction, the object should be fetched and put in a transaction block. In your code, the fetch is done outside transaction.

Comment: @marcadian so the function `check_users` should be a transaction?

Comment: @matheus: depends on what you're trying to do, but I think you need to learn how to use GAE transaction properly. Calling put in a transaction does not make the code do update "transactionally" safe