# Interaction of ndb.toplevel and ndb.transactional

Tags: google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb, google-app-engine-python

Is it possible to get `@ndb.toplevel` to play nicely with `@ndb.transactional`?

What I would like to achieve is a transaction which contains `entity.put_async()` calls, but with the convenience of not having to explicitly wait on the futures. `@ndb.toplevel` would normally do this, but another SO question seems to suggest that it cannot be combined with transactions: ["Does ndb toplevel break transactions?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21506231/does-ndb-toplevel-break-transactions)

I cannot find this explicitly documented anywhere in the App Engine docs. We can reproduce the assertion error shown in that question, but we wrote some tests to see if the `put_async()` calls failed and haven't see any problems. However, since there's possibility of losing data it would be nice to get a more concrete answer here from someone who knows ndb well.

Our simple test code is below.
If we remove both the `ndb.toplevel` and the `ndb.transactional` decorator the test fails, as expected.
However, if we just use the `ndb.transactional` decorator and leave out the `ndb.toplevel` decorator, the test passes, which isn't expected. This makes me worry that perhaps there's just enough overhead in the `ndb.transactional` that the `put_async()` call has enough time to complete, but without any gaurantee, so it might fail unpredictably?

```
class AsyncTestModel(ndb.Model):
    data = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)

@ndb.toplevel
def start_test():
    for _ in range(100):
        test()

    # Check we wrote all the entities
    time.sleep(30)
    entities = AsyncTestModel.query().fetch()
    assert(len(entities) == 1000)


@ndb.transactional(xg=True)
def test():
    for _ in range(10):
        x = AsyncTestModel()
        x.data = make_random_string(1000)
        x.put_async()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fact that the test passes when you only use `@ndb.transactional` is the expected comportement: to ensure that transactions are never partially applied, `@ndb.transactional` wait that all requests are done.

So the code `for _ in range(100): test()` waits that the transaction ends at each iteration.

Thus the following test passes:

```
@ndb.transactional(xg=True)
def test():
    for _ in range(10):
        x = AsyncTestModel()
        x.data = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(1000))
        x.put_async()

for x, _ in enumerate(range(100)):
    test()
    assert(AsyncTestModel.query().count() == (x + 1) * 10)
```

Note: if you use asynchronous queries in transaction, you may look at `@ndb.transactional_async` (documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/async#transactions)).